# how to mention jaxb xsd schema include in catalog like import

Tags: maven, xsd, jaxb2, catalog

I have used catalog file to resolve path of xsd import namespaces with 'REWRITE_SYSTEM' when xsd are in different projects ( projectA is a dependency to projectB ).
But if xsd has import and include in projectA, then how would I specify the maven jar path in catalog file for include as it would not have namespace. Any ideas?